# Flutter - How to await inside a FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-futurebuilder

Please see the comment in the code

```
 return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: exercisesRef.get(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Something went wrong");
    }
... more code

//THIS NEEDS TO BE AWAITED...
 _generateDataTableRowsForCompletedExercises(
                weight,
                reps,
                isToFailure,
              );
```

Its a void function:

```
    void _generateDataTableRowsForCompletedExercises(weight, reps, isToFailure) {
  
  dataRowsForCompletedExercises.add(
      DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text('')),
      DataCell(Text(weight)),
      DataCell(Text(reps)),
      DataCell((isToFailure == true) ? Icon(Icons.check) : Icon(null)),
      
    ]),
  );
  
}
```

Comment: you cannot `await` your method as it does not return `Future` value - it is `void` method

Comment: So how do you deal with this?

Comment: What I want to achieve is the _generateDataTableRowsForCompletedExercises to be executed completely before the execution moves further in the Future Builder; which basically means await... :|

Comment: *"which basically means await..."* - no, `await` is something else: it it used to wait for a future to complete, i gave you a link for more info, again, read [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)

Comment: I read through it, it is in essence the same thing, just that my function doesn't have a return type. I want to await the execution of the Future _generateDataTableRowsForCompletedExercises

Comment: they say: *"The await keyword works only in async functions."* - your `_generateDataTableRowsForCompletedExercises` is NOT `async` method

Comment: I know! :) That is what I am seeking a resolution to.

Comment: I understand that await needs to be applied to a Future and my function is not a Future. It's clear to me. I need a workaround to this. Or any other way of dealing with this.

Comment: I am fetching data through a FutureBuilder and while processing the data, I need to wait for a function to complete execution. This is the entire situation. How do I do this?

Comment: as i said: if you call `_generateDataTableRowsForCompletedExercises` the caller will be waiting untill that method completes (nothing can interrupt it in the middle)

Comment: That is what I thought, but for some reason it is not behaving like that. Let me see one more time.

Comment: For some reason, there was this strange behaviour while debugging. I changed a couple of things, now it seems to be working ok. I appreciate your time and effort.